# AngularJs ng-click function getting runtime error - can't read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Hi i am trying to run a function from my .js file by a button but when i click the button it is not responding and nothing is happening.

Html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src = "groups.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="groupsCtrl">
      <div class="group-jumbotron">
         <h1 class="display-4">Champion's League Groups</h1>
         <p class="lead">The 2018–19 UEFA Champions League group stage began on 18 September and is scheduled to end on 12 December 2018. <br/>
            A total of 32 teams compete in the group stage to decide the 16 places in the knockout phase of the 2018–19 UEFA Champions League.
         </p>
         <hr class="my-1">
         <p>Information about each group can be seen below</p>
      </div>
      <div class="addGroup-Title">
         <h4 class="display-6">Groups:</h4>
         <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
               <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Group Letter</th>
                  <th scope="col">Number of Teams</th>
                  <th scope="col">Matches Played</th>
                  <th scope="col">Top Goalscorer</th>
                  <th scope="col">Top Assists</th>
                  <th scope="col">Most Cards</th>
                  <th scope="col">Total Points</th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="group in leagueGroup">
                  <td>{{group.groupLetter}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.numberOfTeams}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.totalMatchesPlayed}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.topGoalscorer}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.topAssists}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.mostCards}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.totalPoints}}</td>
                  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" ng-click="getSpecificGroup()">Edit</button></td>
                  //THIS BUTTON                
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
                     ng-click="deleteGroupById()">Delete</button></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
```

.js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.groups', ['ngRoute'])

  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/groups', {
      templateUrl: 'groups/groups.html',
      controller: 'groupsCtrl'
    });
  }])

  .controller('groupsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.deleteGroupById = function () {
      const isConfirmed = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Group: ' + $scope.groupData.groupId + '?');

      if (isConfirmed) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups/' + $scope.leagueGroup.groupId)
          .then(function (response) {
            $scope.groupData = response.data;
          });
        $http.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups/' + $scope.groupData.groupId)
          .then(function (response) {
              $scope.response = response.data;
              alert('Group deleted successfully: ' + $scope.groupData.groupId);
            },
            function (error) {
              alert("Error! Group could not be deleted!" + $scope.groupData.groupId);
            });
      }
    };
  });

function getgroupId() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 10);
}
```

Chrome Inspector:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupId' of undefined
at b.$scope.deleteGroupById (groups.js:74)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:16387), <anonymous>:4:165)
at e (angular.js:28815)
at b.$eval (angular.js:19356)
at b.$apply (angular.js:19455)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:28819)
at og (angular.js:3805)
at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:3793)
```

So it should be calling the $scope.deleteGroupById() but unfortunately it is just doing nothing?? 
I have used buttons used submit buttons that work and have also tried to place the button outside of the table but it still does not seem to be responding

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please check your console for errors and add more info about not working state

Comment: Could be an ad blocker suppressing the confirm dialog - have you tried adding a console statement inside `deleteGroupById`?

Comment: not too confident on any of this, what should i add?

Comment: ive updated with what chrome is telling me when i click the button! what im trying to do is delete the data in the corresponding row which the delete button is clicked? @ic3b3rg

Comment: It is in fact invoking the function but that function is getting a run time error because `$scope.groupData` is undefined. The code seems to use it before the server provides it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `ng-repeat` you must send propriety to your `function` so the controller sees what propriety to use. The other mistake is that you tried to access your response before `$http` finish the request.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="group in leagueGroup">
            <td>{{group.groupLetter}}</td>
            <td>{{group.numberOfTeams}}</td>
            <td>{{group.totalMatchesPlayed}}</td>
            <td>{{group.topGoalscorer}}</td>
            <td>{{group.topAssists}}</td>
            <td>{{group.mostCards}}</td>
            <td>{{group.totalPoints}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" ng-click="getSpecificGroup(group)">Edit</button></td> <!-- Send the group to function -->
//THIS BUTTON                
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
ng-click="deleteGroupById(group)">Delete</button></td> <!-- Send the group to function -->
        </tr>
```

And JS

```
// Width group parameter
$scope.deleteGroupById = function (group) {
    const isConfirmed = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Group: ' + group.groupId + '?');

    if (isConfirmed) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups/' + group.groupId)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.groupData = response.data;

                // Delete when you get your response
                $http.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/groups/' + $scope.groupData.groupId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.response = response.data;
                            alert('Group deleted successfully: ' + $scope.groupData.groupId);
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            alert("Error! Group could not be deleted!" + $scope.groupData.groupId);
                        });
            });

    }
};
```